# UIAlertAction - Edit UIAlertAction after it was set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have a class named ManagerClass.

Manager Class has a function showUIAlertController:

```
- (UIAlertController*)showUIAlertController:(NSString *)title  message:(NSString *)message actions:(NSArray<UIAlertAction*>* )actions
```

This function should show alert controller with the parameters received.

So far so good...

Now i would like to take these actions and edit them somehow. Something like:

```
UIAlertAction *action = actions.firstObject;
UIAlertAction *actionCopyWithAdditionalAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:action.title style:action.style handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

     [action "performTheAction"]; //perform the original action 
     [ManagerClass doSomething];         
}];
```

"performTheAction" does not exist - it is just for you to understand what i am trying to achieve.

Does anyone has an idea how this task can be achieved ?

Did not find a way to do that while looking at Apple's UIAlertAction API
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertaction

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to perform a method provided by your code. Then use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(aMethod:)];
```

or when sending an object with:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(aMethod:)
       withObject:(id)object];
```

Note, the self here is referencing to the same class, it could be somewhere else as well.

- Edit *

  UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                                 message:@"This is an alert."
                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

  ```
  UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) { 
             NSLog(@"42.");
             }];

  [alert addAction:defaultAction];
  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
  ```

The console logs out 42. Put instead every action do you need.

Comment: No. I mean to take one UIAlertAction, copy it somehow to a new action and within that new action execute the received action + My Code.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to call a second alert which only displays the first alert and execute some of your code? You can do that in the first alert, too.

```
//Create the UIAlertController
UIAlertController *theAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Your Title" message:@"Your Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

//Add an UIAlertAction which the user can click at
[theAlertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    //Execute your own code 
    //[self myOwnCode];

`//Close the AlertController after your code
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}]];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:theAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
});`

Hope i understand you right.

Comment: Imagine you want a UIAlertController manager. Such that will be responsible to prevent multiple alerts been shown one on top the other. So for each action the manager wants to know that the alert has been dismissed.

A possible way to do it, is to let the manager have the function:

    - (UIAlertController*)showUIAlertController:(NSString *)title  message:(NSString *)message actions:(NSArray<UIAlertAction*>* )actions

And at the manager create the UIAlertController and add to each action some code which inform the manager that the action was taken.

I hope it does make some sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a alert action model instead of a `UIAlertAction`.

so your method would look something like this:

```
- (UIAlertController*)showUIAlertController:(NSString *)title  message:(NSString *)message actions:(NSArray<MyActionModel*>* )actions
```

where `MyActionModel` is a class with 3 properties

```
@interface MyActionModel: NSObject {
    @property NSString * title;
    @property UIAlertActionStyle * style;
    @property ((void)^(UIAlertAction *)) action;
}
```

Then you can create your `UIAlertAction`s when you need them and also add in your manager callbacks.

P.S. Sorry if my Objective-C is not quite right, I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: I took this approach more or less. But used a 'runningBlock' without input or output parameters. This way i could create a UIAlertAction and inside it's block, run my 'runningBlock'.

Comment: It seem that Apple does not provide any way to edit a UIAlertAction.